# How do I select Visual SVN as my source control provider

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, visualsvn

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate which come with TFS. However I am using Visual SVN as my source control.

I have installed VisualSVN server and the Visual Studio plug in.

What should I do to switch from TFS to Visual SVN.

When I go do Tools/Options/Source Control/Plug-in selection, I have the choice between "None" and TFS.

Comment: VisualSVN server != svn client. i'm pretty sure you still need to install a client app

Comment: @Andrea - he said "I have installed VisualSVN server **and the Visual Studio plug in**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not stuck on VisualSVN, try [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/). We use that here, and had no issues in getting it to work with VisualStudio 2010.

AnkhSVN is an open source plugin, so there's no need to pay for a license.

If VisualSVN  is like AnkhSVN, you need to in tall VisualStudio first, then AnkhSVN. Then go into VisualStudio and select *SVN* in the Source Control Plug-in selection.

Answer (score 3):

VisualSVN automatically "just works" when you open a SVN working copy - you don't need to mess with Visual Studio's SCC plugin settings. So you need to look at migrating your source code code into the SVN repository first. When you've done this, just check it out, open the solution and you're done. (You may want to remove all the "SccProjectName/SccProvider..." garbage from your project files beforehand)

To migrate your repository history from TFS to SVN, there's the [TFS2SVN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/) project (I've not used it though).